# Move the z axis on the other side on a 3D plot python

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I move the z-axis of a 3D plot on the other side (including the label, ticks, and numbering). Here is small code and figure of what I mean:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d 

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

ax.set_xlabel("X" , fontsize=20)
ax.set_ylabel("Y", fontsize=20)
ax.set_zlabel("Z" , fontsize=20)

x = np.arange(0,10,0.01)
y = np.ones(len(x))
z = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x,y,z)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D 
import numpy as np


fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

tmp_planes = ax.zaxis._PLANES 
ax.zaxis._PLANES = ( tmp_planes[2], tmp_planes[3], 
                     tmp_planes[0], tmp_planes[1], 
                     tmp_planes[4], tmp_planes[5])
ax.set_xlabel("X" , fontsize=20)
ax.set_ylabel("Y", fontsize=20)
# rotate label
ax.zaxis.set_rotate_label(False)  # disable automatic rotation
ax.set_zlabel("Z axis label" , fontsize=20, rotation=90)
x = np.arange(0,10,0.01)
y = np.ones(len(x))
z = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x,y,z)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Actually I don't want to change the orientation of the plotted stuff (the actual stuff is a lot more complicated so the orientation matters). I want to just label the z-azis on the other side.

Comment: I edited my answer. This is not the best way to do so, but it does the work...

Comment: Thanks a lot! This almost does it! Is there a way to turn the Z-label upside down. If instead of Z you write an actual word, I would like it to be read from bottom to the top, not top to bottom.

Comment: You can simply rotate the label :) I edited my answer, please accept it if It's helpful :)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot!